# NodeJS / Express res.download not sending file

Tags: node.js, express, https

Here is the server code:

```
router.get("/download", (req, res) => {
  console.log("downloading file...");
  const file = `${__dirname}/../downloads/dummy.txt`; 
  res.download(file);
});
```

and here is the client-side JQuery:

```
const downloadSoftware = () => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/download",
    success: function(res) {
      console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(res) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<a id="downloadParser" onclick="downloadSoftware()">
Download Parser
</a>
```

My problem is when I click on the  tag, nothing happens in my browser when a file should be downloading.

EDIT: 
when I click the  tag i get this in the console for NodeJS:

```
GET /download 304 1.751 ms - -
```

Comment: Please show the code for your client-side Javascript method called `downloadSoftware()` if you have one. If you don't your `<a ... >` tag needs `href` rather than `onclick`. Also look at the console log in your devtools.

Comment: Can you please show the implementation of the `downloadSoftware()`